# Android - Firebase FCM and Android Studio Emulators, intermittent behaviour

Tags: android, firebase, android-emulator, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm not yet entirely sure why but it seems that when I use the Firebase FCM services and have 2 or more emulators running on my Android Studio the Firebase FCM API behaviour goes nuts.

> The Flow

A quick example is:

1 - I subscribe to a topic

`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topicName).addOnCompleteListener...`

2 - Send messages (All good so far, I get all messages)

3 - Unsubscribe  `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(topicName).addOnCompleteListener...`

4 - Send messages (all good so far, I don't get messages anymore)

> The problem:

When I repeat the same thing with two or more devices, it simply does not work, even though I get the response of the `addOnCompleteListener` method, let's say "unsubscribed", I still get messages.

Points to notice:

1 - Yes, I'm sure I unsubscribe only 1 device between the two, and the one I unsubscribe keeps getting messages (I can see in the log files).

2 - No, the problem does not happen when I use one emulator only

3 - I've already tried to use a real device via debug mode (connected via USB cable and I still have the same behaviour when running in parallel with another emulator)

4 - Yes, I'm sure I get the response from the `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(topicName)` method before sending messages.

> Specs:

```
Android Studio: 3.1.2
```

Firebase:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
```

> My assumption

There's something broken between the identification of more than one emulator when it's run in parallel, and therefore the Firebase topics API cannot distinguish accurately which is which.

Any thoughts?

Cheers in advance.